# C++ add array with unicode character

Tags: c++, arrays, unicode

i just wanna see why this code isn't running ? anybody has an idea how to solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(){

        _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t alphabets[26] = { 'ض', 'ص', 'ث', 'ز', 'ق', 'ف', 'غ', 'ع', 'ه', 'خ', 'ح', 'ج', 'د', 'ش', 'س', 'ي', 'ب', 'ل', 'ا', 'ت', 'ن', 'م', 'ك', 'ط', 'ئ' };
    wchar_t  rString[20];

    srand(time(NULL));

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 20) {
        int temp = rand() % 26;
        rString[i] = alphabets[temp];
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        wprintf(L"%s",rString[i]);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

the idea here is that i need the output in arabic, but after searching a lot i didn't found anything.

Comment: `%s` is for strings, not characters.

Comment: declare `temp` outside `while` loop

Comment: i fixed it but still posting " ????????"

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil still giving a  " ???????" output

Comment: see comment of @tkausl

Comment: @tkausl i changed it to %c , instead i wrote wcout<<rString[i];

Comment: @najibhashem please put your solution in an answer below and accept your own answer as the solution, for everyone here to enjoy!

Comment: A `'c'` character is a char.  You may need to use `L'c'` for your wchar_t literals.

Comment: The alphabets array is defined as 26, but only 25 characters are provided.  So `alphabets[25]` will be 0, or `L'\0'`.